# Executable not found in /bin directory

Tags: ros, opencv, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I am trying to make ROS and the opencv work together for bringing up the edge detection on a quadrotor called the ardrone.
The code compiled successfully and was built using rosmake with 0 failures.
But driver file was to found in the bin which was created.

I am using ROS-electric,ubuntu 10.10
Any suggestion please.
This is my rosmake output:

`[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['ardrone_kar']                      [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ardrone_kar']                              [ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/metallo/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120209-145539 [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ardrone_kar'] to: ['ardrone_kar']                    [ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages ardrone_kar.  This may take a few seconds. [ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages              [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                       [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild No Makefile in package rosbuild [rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                     [rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common            [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                         [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib                    [rosmake-3] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                        [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                        [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                        [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang No Makefile in package roslang [rosmake-0] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                       [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits      [rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                       [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime                  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                           [rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs                [rosmake-0] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp                [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                     [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                       [rosmake-3] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2                  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole            [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                       [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                       [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean                [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs      [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                         [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                      [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam                [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph                [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster              [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                          [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                        [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp                    [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                         [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                      [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy                      [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout                    [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib              [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit                  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                      [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch No Makefile in package roslaunch [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                        [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest                  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                    [rosmake-1] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools          [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                         [rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag                    [rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbagmigration [ make ]                                [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbagmigration ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbagmigration No Makefile in package rosbagmigration [rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs      [rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                    [rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs          [rosmake-1] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                                [rosmake-2] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                      [rosmake-1] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge              [rosmake-1] Starting >>> ardrone_kar [ make ]                                    [rosmake-1] Finished <<< ardrone_kar [PASS] [ 0.19 seconds ]                     [ rosmake ] Results:                                                             [ rosmake ] Built 33 packages with 0 failures.                                   [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                          [ rosmake ] /home/metallo/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120209-145539`

I have added the cmakelist.txt for further refrence:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

set(RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

rosbuild_gensrv()

rosbuild_add_executable(ardrone_kar src/ardrone_kar.cpp)

rosbuild_add_library(ardrone_kar src/ardrone_kar.cpp)
```

Output for make command:

*make

```
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_premsgsrvgen
[  0%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_cpp
[  0%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_lisp
[  0%] Built target rospack_gensrv
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
[100%] Buildinmake
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_premsgsrvgen
[  0%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_cpp
[  0%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_lisp
[  0%] Built target rospack_gensrv
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ardrone_kar.dir/src/ardrone_kar.o
In file included from /home/metallo/ros/ardrone_kar/src/ardrone_kar.cpp:5:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: In static member function ‘static boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > > sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg(const IplImage*, std::string)’:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:408: warning: ‘static bool sensor_msgs::CvBridge::fromIpltoRosImage(const IplImage*, sensor_msgs::Image&, std::string)’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:307)
/home/metallo/ros/ardrone_kar/src/ardrone_kar.cpp: In function ‘void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr&)’:
/home/metallo/ros/ardrone_kar/src/ardrone_kar.cpp:9: warning: ‘sensor_msgs::CvBridge::CvBridge()’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:64)
Linking CXX shared library lib/libardrone_kar.so
[100%] Built target ardrone_kar
[100%] Built target rospack_gensrv_all
g CXX object CMakeFiles/ardrone_kar.dir/src/ardrone_kar.o
In file included from /home/metallo/ros/ardrone_kar/src/ardrone_kar.cpp:5:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: In static member function ‘static boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > > sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg(const IplImage*, std::string)’:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:408: warning: ‘static bool sensor_msgs::CvBridge::fromIpltoRosImage(const IplImage*, sensor_msgs::Image&, std::string)’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:307)
/home/metallo/ros/ardrone_kar/src/ardrone_kar.cpp: In function ‘void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr&)’:
/home/metallo/ros/ardrone_kar/src/ardrone_kar.cpp:9: warning: ‘sensor_msgs::CvBridge::CvBridge()’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:64)
Linking CXX shared library lib/libardrone_kar.so
[100%] Built target ardrone_kar
[100%] Built target rospack_gensrv_all*
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12963/executable-not-found-in-/bin-directory/) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-02-09**:
"But driver file was to found in the bin which was created." - this looks like a description of the problem, but it doesn't make any sense to me. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to have the same target name for the library and the executable.  I believe the 2nd declaration of the target will shadow the previous one.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that you add `rosbuild_add_executable(executable_name src/source_file.cpp)` to CMakeLists.txt.

**EDIT**:

Try using `make` instead of `rosmake` for a more detailed output.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on 2012-02-09**:
I tried make command  too the results are the same.

**Comment by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on 2012-02-09**:
Yes it was there all along .I checked it. But it doesn't have any effect it seems. I have uploaded the cmakelist too please do have a look at it. thanks